# In the squares of a 3 × 3 chessboard are written the signs + and − as described in Figure 11(a). Consider the operations ...

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

In the squares of a 3 × 3 chessboard are written the signs + and − as described in
Figure 11(a). Consider the operations in which one is allowed to simultaneously
change all signs in some row or column. Can one change the given configuration to
the one in Figure 11(b) by applying such operations finitely many times?[image]

Comment: Nice problem, any thoughts?

Comment: what is the source of this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say you can't. Consider only the 2x2 upper left sub-board and the parity(=product of all signs) on that sub-board. Every of your operations does not change that parity, although you would have to change it to come from (a) to (b).

Comment: +1. I was thinking along the same lines. Another way to think about it: make an auxiliary matrix consisting of 1's where the sign is changed and 0's where the sign is not changed. To get a possible combination the corners of every rectangle whose sides are parallel to the rows and columns must all have an even sum. You prove that one of these blocks has an odd sum -- fails!

Comment: I think my proof is easier to understand :)

Comment: Please try not answer questions that read like exercises in a text or a contest.  Learn more here [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1).  Thank you.